# Linux Mint gets stuck at boot from Live-CD

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I am trying to install Linux Mint (Cinnamon) from a CD. It will act like it is loading for a while, the CD drive will make a ton of noise for a while, and then everything just freezes (the CD drive will go silent). I tried this a few times and then started in `compatibility mode`. Every time, I get the following:

```
failed to load file amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin
```

I'm trying to install on an older Toshiba Satellite laptop (with Ubuntu currently installed). Any ideas on a fix ?

Comment: It's possible that the CD is damaged. Or even worst, the CD drive. Try it on a different computer and with a different CD if possible.

Comment: The CD worked on several other computers, so it may well be the drive. I tried booting from USB, but the laptop will not even read the USB.

Comment: @5space, it might have worked and gotten scratched later, or your Toshiba's CD drive is pickier than the others. Clean the CD, _carefully_ clean the lens of the drive (it shows when you eject the empty drive). Check the installation media. Download, check, and burn a new copy, at a slow speed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common defect in newer mint & ubuntu versions. It doesn't have the correct AMD & intel drivers & controllers for many computers. Use an older version or a different linux. It will even fail on a live install on windows on the same machine. I find Debian versions easily install on machines that mint & ubuntu hang, freeze, & fail on.

Comment: I agree. Here's my experience on an ASUS_n551VW laptop in groped to load a live distro from usb-drive: -DEBIAN-LIVE_8.6 loads ok; -UBUNTU_15.10 loads ok; -MINT-SARAH_18 gets stuck; -UBUNTU_16.10 gets stuck.